# Application of squeeze theorem to $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x^4\cos(\frac{\pi}{x^2})+1$

Tags: calculus

Use squeeze theorem to evaluate

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x^4\cos(\frac{\pi}{x^2})+1$$

Can I sandwich it between $-x^4\cos(\frac{\pi}{x^2})+1$ and $x^4\cos(\frac{\pi}{x^2})+1$?

Comment: $x^4cos(\frac{\pi}{x^2})+1$ is the original expression you are trying to evaluate the limit of! If you know the limit for it already you don't need the squeeze theorem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can squeeze using $1-x^4$ and $1+x^4$. First, show $1-x^4 \leq 1+x^4cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x^2}\right) \leq 1+x^4$. Then we can use the squeeze theorem to show $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} 1+x^4cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x^2}\right) = 1$ as $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} 1 + x^4 = 1 = \displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} 1 - x^4$.